# I want to remove rows based on the date column to keep the latest entry, grouped by the name

Tags: pandas, excel

For each person I want their latest role entry (by the date field). I.e below keeping rows 1 and 3

```
Name    Date    Role
John    01/08/2023  A
John    01/07/2023  B
Steve   01/06/2023  B
Steve   01/04/2023  A
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Name': ['John', 'John', 'Steve', 'Steve'], 
         'Date': ['01/08/2023', '01/07/2023', '01/06/2023', '01/04/2023'], 
         'Role': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Code**

```
df.groupby('Name').tail(1)
```

output:

```
    Name    Date        Role
1   John    01/07/2023  B
3   Steve   01/04/2023  A
```

Comment: `John    01/08/2023  A` is the latest

Comment: @jynxmaze then sort by Date before groupby